# SAPUI5 multiple users working on one table entry

Tags: sapui5, multi-tenant, hana

I'm currently developing an application in the SAP BTP for multiple users. In the application you have one table where all responsibilities of a specific task are written down. These responsibilities may overlap between the users, which means that for one responsibility multiple users are mentioned.

In the application the users should click on either accept or reject if they still are responsible for this task. After they have given their feedback, they can click on a save button to write everything via a batch submit to the hana db. If they are not responsible anymore their name should be removed from the tasks and they should not see this task anymore.

The problem I am facing is that currently everything is stored in one database table and if one user gives feedback to some entries while another user works on the same entries, the user who saves his entries last will override the first one.

I have tried searching for a delta insert into the database or to live update after each user input or to lock the data when another user is currently working. But none of these seem to work fine, because users would still be able to override each others entries or they may lock some entries forever.

My question therefore is, what is the usual approach to manage multiple user inputs on a single table or is using a single table a bad practise at first?

My second question would be if sapui5 supports this approach or if I can handle this in another way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do server-side validation, before the save action.

UI5 does not support this directly, you can handle it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Because we are stateless with ui5 / data you could use the draft concept
https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/draft-handling/

Or something like already said backend logic with checks before safe.

Answer (score 0):

In this task I don't see any problem if we have task_id and user_name of responsible represented as as unique key columns in the table of actions. Then each user accepting or rejecting a task works with unique record in the table and we have no problem with concurent updates then as I see it.

In case they need to write to the same unique row of the table it's not what I could recommend for this task. But if it's inevitable, one could try locking mechanism with creating lock object with exclusive write lock.

Before action of approve/decline is really performed on database table this lock should be acquired and only then actual info could be refreshed from locked row and updated accordingly. You will probably also need to enable softstate for odata service and setup period of lifetime for the service before locks will be released automatically.